# Is there a way to isolate native-object extensions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

You can extend native objects in javascript. For example, [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) extends Array, String, and Function among other things. Native-object extensions can be very useful, but inherently break encapsulation - ie if someone uses the same extension name (overwriting another extension) things will break.

It would be incredibly nice if you could extend objects for a *particular* scope. E.g. being able to do something like this in node.js:

```
// myExtension1.js
Object.prototype.x = 5

exports.speak = function() {
  var six = ({}.x+1)
  console.log("6 equals: "+six)
}

// myExtension2.js
Object.prototype.x = 20

exports.speak = function() {
  var twenty1 = ({}.x+1)
  console.log("21 equals: "+twenty1)
}
```

and have this work right:

```
// test.js

var one = require('myExtension1')
var two = require('myExtension2')

one.speak(); // 6 equals: 6
two.speak(); // 21 equals: 21
```

Of course in reality, this will print out "6 equals: 21" for the first one.

Is there any way, via any mechanism, to do something where this is possible? The mechanisms I'm interesting in hearing about include:

- Pure javascript
- Node.js
- C++ extensions to Node.js

Comment: Can anyone rule out a node.js c++ extension?

Comment: Not quite, that's asking how to define a non-enumerable property. This is asking how to isolate native-objects between modules

Comment: @Bergi if I'm correct, mind removing the note at the top?

Comment: Yup, sorry for my overhasty close vote - I should've read the question better. Actually I'd love to have such module-scoped prototype extensions, but they always seemed impossible to me so I never asked - +1!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do that currently in node, because node shares the same built-in objects across modules.

This is bad because it could brings to unexpected side effects, like it happened in the browsers history in the past, and that's why now everyone is yelling "don't extend built-in object".

Other commonJS environment are following more the original commonJS specs, so that you do not share built-in object, but every module has its own. For instance in jetpack, the Mozilla SDK to build Firefox's add-on, it works in this way: so you the built-in objects are per module and if you extend one you can't clash.

Anyway, in general I believe that extending built-in object nowadays is not really necessary and should be avoided.

Comment: Interesting information about the commonJS spec. I disagree with the sentiment of "is not necessary" since closures, objects, and anything not-assembly is "not necessary". It sure is useful tho.

Comment: That's my point, I don't think is useful at all. Just for shims, but shims can be global too. It's also true that I moved from OOP approach in JS to a more functional ones over the years, so definitely my opinion is also driven by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since a native type only has a single source for its prototype. In general I would discourage mucking with the prototype of native types. Not only are you limiting your portability (as you pointed out), but you may also be unknowingly overwriting existing properties or future properties. This also creates a lot of "magic" in your code that a future maintainer will have a hard time tracking down. The only real exception to this rule is polyfils. If your environment has not implemented a new feature yet then a polyfil can provide you this.

Comment: Are you ruling out node.js extensions or just pure javascript?

Comment: There may be a node js extension for this, but I'm going to take a wild guess and say there isn't. You might want to look in to mixins for the type of behavior you are talking about.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if its even possible to *make* a node.js extension for this - like.. myself